# .htaccess redirects without extension in url

Tags: .htaccess

I'm hiding my file extensions with

```
RewriteEngine On

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://example.com/folder/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://example.com/folder/$1 [R=301,L]

# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

When I navigate to this link 
http://localhost/website/profile?user=user01&nofollow=1

I'm redirected here
http://example.com/folder/profile?user=user01

I've taken .php out of the url. Why does it redirect me?

Comment: Yes it's inside the /website/ directory. I don't completely understand how this code works. I copied it from a post here on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Have it this way inside `/website/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /website/

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php[?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ $1 [R=301,L,NC]

# Resolve .php file for extension-less php urls
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this.

Comment: This works but if someone adds .php to filenames, I get ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

I noticed when I take the '&' symbol out of my url it works. Maybe '&' needs to be added to the RewriteRule, but I don't know where it should go.

Comment: Yes, 

http://localhost/website/profile?user=user01&nofollow=1

When I remove the & symbol I'm not redirected to example.com

Comment: Do you have more rules in this .htaccess?

Comment: No just the ones posted.

Comment: Then rules are not culprit, there might be something in PHP code. Test in Chrome dev tool and disable caching. Then open your page and check Networking tab to see what are the 301 URLs you're seeing there.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L,NE]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```